# Uncaught syntax error inval or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello im still learning the javascript and jquery. I want to validate the form and thats is fixed now. But when i click on the submit button there needs to be a message in form-message if you havent fill all fields.
He opens a new page (mail.php) and then shows the message from fill all fields.

But when i place a , after ("mail.php") he shows the error what stays in the title.
Someone can explain me whats wrong on my code? and maybe send a fix on it

```js
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var naam = $("#naam").val();
            var straat = $("#straat").val();
            var huisnummer = $("#huisnummer").val();
            var postcode = $("#postcode").val();
            var woonplaats = $("#woonplaats").val();
            var land = $("#land").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var bericht = $("#bericht").val();
            var submit =$("form-submit").val();
            $(".form-message").load("mail.php" {
                naam: naam,
                straat: straat,
                huisnummer: huisnummer,
                postcode: postcode,
                woonplaats: woonplaats,
                land: land,
                email: email,
                bericht: bericht,
                submit: submit

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
        <div id="frmContact">
            <h1 class="title">Contact formulier</h1>
            <p class="form-message"></p>
                <div>
                    <label class="label-naam">* Naam:</label>
                    <span id="naam-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Straat:</label>
                    <span id="straat-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="straat" id="straat" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Huisnummer</label>
                    <span id="huisnummer-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="number" name="huisnummer" id="huisnummer" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>Huisnummertoevoeging</label>
                    <span id="huistoevoeging-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="huistoevoeging" id="huistoevoeging" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Postcode</label>
                    <span id="postcode-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Woonplaats</label>
                    <span id="woonplaats-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="woonplaats" id="woonplaats" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label for="land-info">* Kies een land:</label>
                    <select name="land" id="land">
                        <option value="nederland">NL</option>
                        <option value="belgie">BE</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Email</label>
                    <span id="email-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="test@test.nl" class="InputBox" requierd>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>* Bericht</label> 
                    <span id="bericht-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht" class="InputBox" placeholder="Typ een bericht" cols="60" rows="6" requierd></textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
            <button id="form-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Verzenden</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.load("mail.php" {...})` is a syntax error. _"But when i place a , after ("mail.php") he shows the error what stays in the title"_ - That statement makes no sense because adding a comma would make that valid syntax: `.load("mail.php", {...})`.

Comment: The selector in `$("form-submit").val();` is invalid. There's no `<form-submit>` element in HTML4/5. That should be an id selector -> `#form-submit`